# How to create and use a global class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I want to create a variable that must hold the properties of a hardware driver. The properties must be defined in one part of my code (currently app_main() in main.ccp) and will be used in a different part (e.g. in driverUser.cpp).

My current solution aims at creating a global class NimBLEGluer in nimBLEdriver.h . I have read various posts relating to this but still no success. The code below shows the three parts:  class definition, setting some test variable in main() and assessing the variable in driverUser. I can successfully the initial value of testPointer from 13 to 7 in main.ccp, but in driverUser the value is still the initial value (13).

The code in driverUser is executed after changing of the value in main().

My compiler complains when I do not use instantiation with NimBLEGluer NimBLEData; in both locations.

How can I achieve that retrieval of testPointer has a result of 7 ?

(a number of lines have been commented because they cause some other issues, to be attacked later)

```
/*******************
*nimBLEdriver.h
********************/
class NimBLEGluer {
    
    public:
    //constructor
    //NimBLEGluer(); //causes a: ../main/main.cpp:564: undefined reference to `NimBLEGluer::setPointer(int)'
                   //in that line there is NO reference to this class at all!
    //destructor
    //virtual ~NimBLEGluer();  

    int testPointer = 123;  //initial value for testing
    /*
    void setPointer( int inp);
    int getPointer( void ){
        return testPointer;
        };
    */        
    }; 

//NimBLEGluer::NimBLEGluer() {}  //causes a: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'constexpr NimBLEGluer::NimBLEGluer()'

//NimBLEGluer::~NimBLEGluer() {}

extern NimBLEGluer NimBLEDAta;  //to make it globally accessible without intantiating it again ?? 
/************************************************************************************************************/

/***** in main.cpp, which has a #include "nimBLEdriver.h" *****/
  NimBLEGluer NimBLEData;
  printf("MAIN testPointer: %d\n", NimBLEData.testPointer); //result: 123
  NimBLEData.testPointer = 7;
  printf("MAIN testPointer: %d\n", NimBLEData.testPointer); //result: 7
  

 /***** in driverUser.cpp, which has a #include "nimBLEdriver.h" *****/ 
  NimBLEGluer NimBLEData; //needs to be here, but resets the value of testPointer
  printf("RtMidiOut testPointer: %d\n", NimBLEData.testPointer);  //result: 123
```

Comment: You should have `NimBLEGluer NimBLEData` in exactly one .cpp file in the entire program. Your header file contains `extern NimBLEGluer NimBLEDAta` and it is precisely what you need to refer to it in other .cpp files. No other declarations are necessary.

Comment: That is a useful insight! Thanks.   Is there a way to "transfer" information between pieces of code in multiple cpp's ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you want to share data between translation units, then yes, every time you use `NimBLEData` it refers to the same object, thanks to `extern NimBLEGluer NimBLEDAta` declaration. A better approach would be to avoid global variables but pass your data as function arguments.

Comment: I agree with you comment on using global values and will look for a way to design functions for my use case.   In my example I have three (or 2 and a header file ? depending on the definition) translation units. I added extern now in all three places. Now I get a:  esp-idf/main/libmain.a(main.cpp.obj):(.literal.app_main+0x0): undefined reference to `NimBLEData'.

Comment: OK, I interpreted your answer as: it is possible to share data between translation units (different .cpp's ) when I use extern. Is that a correct interpretation?  When I have extern only in the header file and not in both cpp's then I have the situation as in my example, which does not give the desired result. So, I tried to add extern in both cpp's.  What did you mean in your suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239818/discussion-between-f-ckx-and-n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m).

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @n.1.8e9-where's-my-share m.   I had to use NimBLEGluer NimBLEData in only one translation unit. In the end I removed this line from driverUser.cpp.  After removing the TYPO in nimBLEdriver.h   (NimBLEDAta >>> NimBLEData)  I can access and print testPointer in driverUser without instantiation of the object in that translation unit.

So: it IS possible to share data between code in different .cpp s in this way.